# Saving "row headers" from .describe() to a file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to save "row headers" (for the lack of better description) from

[describe()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) to a file alongside with generated statistics. Command line output of the below code produces

```
In [262]: df.describe().Values
Out[262]: 
count    5.000000
mean     3.000000
std      1.581139
min      1.000000
25%      2.000000
50%      3.000000
75%      4.000000
max      5.000000
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

however saved file produces just the numeric values
[file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHKE5.png)

```
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

data = {'Names': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'Values': [1,2,3,4,5]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

workbook = Workbook('Test.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
Report_Sheet.write_column(0, 0, df.describe().Values)
workbook.close()
```

How do I save "row headers" (count, mean, std, min, 25%, etc.) to a file?

Many thanks!

Comment: check pandas df.describe().to_excel()

Comment: Thanks, Wen! Using `.to_excel()` does save "row headers" . ` import pandas as pd

data = {'Names': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'Values': [1,2,3,4,5]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Test3.xlsx')
df.describe().to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()`